# How to get ParameterInfo Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, stack-trace

I am using the below code to get Calling Method name and its parameter inside a method.

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
var methodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
var parameters = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().GetParameters();

foreach (var parameterInfo in parameters)
{
    var name = parameterInfo.Name;
    var value = "How to get value?";
}
```

Now my question is to get the value of that parameter. 
Any ideas?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. But if you really insist on doing it there are some ways thats quite more complicated. have a read here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769651/how-get-value-of-parameters-in-stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way of doing that. The only working approach I've seen is adding code to your application that will attach external debugger to itself and read stack information. John Robbins is showing this is his [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622027) using modified sources of [MDBG](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19621).