# How to get a class instance from a Method Base in a StackTrace

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to provide some helpful message to debug a particular exception and for that I need to access the instances of all the classes of the methods in the stack.

Let's take the following code as an example. Say I have the following class:

```
Public Class Foo
  Public Name As String
  Public Sub DoStuff(Optional N As Integer = 10)
    If N = 0 Then Throw New Exception("Boom")
    Dim C As New Foo
    C.Name = "Class level =  " & N
    C.DoStuff(N - 1)
  End Sub
End Class
```

It will cause an exception. What I want to do is to capture the values of Name of all the Foo instances in the stack.

```
Try
  Dim C As New Foo
  C.Name = "Base class"
  C.DoStuff()
Catch ex As Exception
  Dim St As New StackTrace(ex)
  For i As Integer = 0 To St.FrameCount - 1
    Dim M = St.GetFrame(i).GetMethod()
    Console.WriteLine(M.Name & " " & M.DeclaringType.ToString)
  Next
End Try
```

I am almost these, I can get the method and the type of the classes in the call stack, but what I am missing is to be able to get the actual instance in order to be able to access the field Name of each class Foo in the stack.

Is that even possible?

thanks
Charles

Comment: If you're trying to debug something like this in the IDE, the `System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplayAttribute` may be useful.

Comment: Thanks. That would be outside of Visual Studio though. This is for a sort of excel-like software. I can spot circular references easily, which generate an exception. What I am trying to do is to help the user find what the circular reference was by going through the stack of calculation trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [Is it possible to get parameters' values for each frame in call stack in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819576/is-it-possible-to-get-parameters-values-for-each-frame-in-call-stack-in-net).

What would be needed is access to whole data stack & heap the of .NET process. I don't think it is easy (and even possible). What is recommended is use logging mechanism instead.